# pull objects with a matching attribute from ngrx/store in Angular2

Tags: angular, ngrx

if I have a store that consists of `preferences` with a sample looking like:

`preferences: [{
  name: 'pref1',
  accepted: true,
  contents: {
    type: 'boolean',
    value: true
  }, {
  name: 'pref2',
  accepted: false,
  contents: {
    type: 'boolean',
    value: true
  },
  ...
]`

and using a `ngrx` store with a `reducer` I want two different values.  The first I want is all the preferences which I can grab using:

`this.preferences = this._store.select('preferences');`

I'd also like to grab only the preferences with `accepted: true`, and keep the result as an `Observable` so I can pipe it into an Angular 2 module using the `async` pipe.  I've tried things like:

`this.acceptedPreferences = this._store.select('preferences').filter(preference => preference.accepted === true);`

but I can't find the correct syntax, and haven't been able to find a good example of what I'm looking for to make it work.  My real application is more complicated, and I need to keep track of a few attributes of my stored objects to created multiple subsets of data to pass through my application.  It's possible I should be storing them all using individual reducers, but since they all reference the same data set, it seemed appropriate to handle the subsets using `Observables` and filtering out the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preferences won't be flattened, the value emitted by the `select` will be an array of preferences, with a new array emitted upon changes.

You can use an RxJS `map` operator and the `Array.prototype.filter` method to filter your array of preferences:

```
this.acceptedPreferences = this._store
    .select('preferences')
    .map((preferences) => preferences.filter((preference) => preference.accepted));
```

The resultant `acceptedPreferences` observable will emit an array of accepted preferences whenever the preferences in the store change.